# Change font size for output in a single chunk in R Markdown PDF document

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I have an R Markdown with bookdown document that has several chunks of R code.  After each chunk I output the resulting tibble table is output.  I have one tibble output that has several columns that move out of the margin and am trying to figure out how to reduce the font size of this one particular chunk (leaving all out chunks output unchanged).  I want to leave the "echoed" code font size unchanged.

Is this possible?  I've read a few of the other posts here but all seem to address global font size changes, rather than one for a particular chunk.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my YAML header too:

```
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{indentfirst}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \def\tightlist{}
  \setlength\parindent{24pt}
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::tf_article
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. What is a *tibble table*? `kable()` output? A [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `htmltools` with `results='asis'` inside chunck, or with `r ...` outside chunck :

````
```{r, results = 'asis',echo = F}
htmltools::h3("Test big font")
htmltools::h4('Test medium font')
htmltools::h5('Test smaller font')
```
`r htmltools::h3("Outside chunck")`
````

[image]